# Can I run ZPL commands by CMD on Windows OS?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have zebra gk420t printer and I want to create .bat file for reset counters on printer. There will be one command for it: ~RO1. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

See this [q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053516/printing-zpl-file-using-batch-file-issue) for how to print a ZPL file via batch file.

Create one with the content `~RO1` and anything else you might need.

Then call the batch file like this:
`C:\Path\to\your\batchfile.bat “YourZPLfile.zpl“`