# Printing ZPL file using Batch File Issue

Tags: batch-file, netsuite, zebra-printers, network-printers

We run NetSuite for our shipping software and use Zebra ZP450 printer to print the thermal label.
The software downloads a .zpl file which I have assigned to run with a batch file, script here:

```
Net use LPT2: \\%ComputerName%\ZebraFedex

Copy %1 LPT2

Net use LPT2: /Delete
```

I have installed this on probably 20 or more computers without an issue. But the last two will initiate the batch file but not print.

I was able to hit pause on the batch file and here is what I got:

> C:\users\noah\downloads\net use LPT2: \(ComputerName)\ZebraFedex
>
> The command completed successfully
>
> C:\Users\Noah\Downloads\Copy LPT2
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.   0 files copied
>
> C:\Users\Noah\Downloads>Net use LPT2: /Delete

I've checked my file association, which seems correct since I see the command prompt flash on the screen. I have no idea here...

[image: Here is the screenshot of the batch file working successfully on another computer]

Working successfully on another computer

[image: Here is the screenshot of the batch file not working]

Problem on puzzling computer

Comment: There seems to be some unrendered symbols in your post. If you add a line `PAUSE` after the last line of the script, batch should well, pause, of all things. Try editing-in a cropped screenshot since the vagaries of formatting and editing seem to have obfuscated the actual messages. What seems obvious from the response `C:\Users\Noah\Downloads\Copy LPT2` is that the batch has been run with no parameter.

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Thanks for taking a look. Could it have something to do with permission levels or login credentials? Just something I stumbled across on a different thread...

Comment: Quote: `What seems obvious from the response C:\Users\Noah\Downloads\Copy LPT2 is that the batch has been run with no parameter. – Magoo yesterday`

Comment: This batch file is taken straight from Oracle instructions and runs perfectly on quite a few other computers. Page 26 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60665_01/netsuitecs_gs/NSSIP/NSSIP.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here's my batch to transfer file to my venerable TLP2844:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
 IF EXIST "%%a" (COPY /b "%%~a" \\%computername%\TLP2844
 ) ELSE (
  IF EXIST "%%a.txt" (
   COPY /b "%%~a.txt" \\%computername%\TLP2844
  ) else (
   ECHO Neither "%%a" nor "%%a.txt" appears to EXIST
  )
 )
)
```

where I have a printer called `TLP2844` installed as a `ZDesigner TLP 2844` device on USB003.

---

The problem, as shown by the graphics I've included in your question (saves running off chasing links) is that the label file `C:\users\melan\downloads\UPSSHIPPINGLABEL1700448.zpl` is being provided to the batch as `%1` (first parameter). On the problem installation, no filename (presumably `C:\users\Noah\downloads\UPSSHIPPINGLABEL???????.zpl` is being provided to the batch as `%1`.

Therefore it's not a batch problem, but a problem with `Netsuite`.

From your .pdf, on page 26 :

To install a thermal printer driver on a Windows PC:
...
5. In the Share Name field, enter the name of the printer. For example, `LP 2844`.
The printer name cannot contain spaces.

So you're told the printer name cannot contain spaces, but the example printer name contains a space....Excellent! (shows my level of confidence in the product, but not actually directly relevant to the problem) :(

Personally, I'd change your batch file to

```
Copy %1 \\%ComputerName%\ZebraFedex
```

Perhaps you'd try that after fixing the problem where `Netsuite` fails to deliver the filename to the batch. Perhaps it's set up to produce `.pdf`s on the computer in question (That's a wild guess)

---

In response to reply:

Please change your batch file (temporarily for test purposes) to this:

```batch-file
Echo File to print : "%1"

Net use LPT2: \\%ComputerName%\ZebraFedex

Copy %1 LPT2

Net use LPT2: /Delete

PAUSE
```

which will report the filename supplied by `Netsuite` to the batch file on the console window, then keep the window open at the end of the batch until the open window receives a keystroke.

Please report results for both a "working" and a "buggy" installation.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. NetSuite downloads the ZPL file automatically to the downloads folder, from there I have .zpl files set to open automatically. So it shouldn't be a NetSuite issue. It just seems like it isn't finding the file for some reason. Folder sharing or firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Change `.bat` file like below, replacing the printer share name with your own.  Happened on one of our critical computers that is also the host for FedEx/UPS.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\net.exe use LPT2: \\%ComputerName%\Zebra_ZP500_Shipping_FedEx1

Copy %1 LPT2

C:\WINDOWS\system32\net.exe use LPT2: /Delete
```

Thank you Noah Schultz for the `Pause` suggestion for batch file, and to QWERTY for article on Net command issue

[Reference](https://serverfault.com/questions/50173/error-net-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pro)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).